# Glare node missing?

Tags: modifiers

I have issues to find a glare node in shading mode. I have latest version of blender and and I Do as in all tutorials in internet but trouble is I cant find glare node.

Comment: hello, the Glare node is in the Compositor, not the Shader Editor, maybe it's your mistake?

Comment: Yes I had idea of that. I need to start learning how to use compositor mode thanks